# No Launcher activity found even after putting the correct action and category

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have followed several threads on stack overflow but this is the error still shown:

> No Launcher activity found!
>
> The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Here is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="transapps.android_bluetooth_host"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="transapps.android_bluetooth_host.BluetoothHost"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.inent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: make sure that class path in activity name is correct

Comment: Do you have `BluetoothHost.java` in your package?

Comment: Yes it is. My main activity is "BluetoothHost.java" residing in the folder "src/transapp.android_bluetooth_host/"

Comment: Try a Project/Clean. If not enough, try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: @DerGolem Tried both!

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with the sdk version? I downloaded the code from the web. There is no error shown though. I configured the build path accordingly.

Comment: OK, so it sometimes helps to copy all the inner code of your class to a text file, destroy your class, make a new one and paste the code inside the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did it just now, still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo. Your intent filter category says "android.inent" which will not match the category name expected by the launcher.